# Javascript re-assign let variable with destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

In my React app I am using airbnb's eslint style guide which will throw an error if I do not use destructuing.

In the situation below, I first use `let` to assign the two variables `latitude` and `longitude` to the coordinates of the first item in an array of location objects. Then I try to use destructuring to re-assign their values if the user has given me access to their location.

```
let latitude = locations[0].coordinates[1];
let longitude = locations[0].coordinates[0];

if (props.userLocation.coords) {
  // doesn't work - unexpected token
  { latitude, longitude } = props.userLocation.coords;

  // causes linting errors
  // latitude = props.userLocation.coords.latitude;
  // longitude = props.userLocation.coords.longitude;
}
```

Destructuring inside the `if` statement causes an `unexpected token` error.

Re-assigning the variables the old fashioned way causes an `ESlint: Use object destructuring` error.

Answer (score 336, accepted):

```
 ({ latitude, longitude } = props.userLocation.coords);
```

Destructuring needs to be either after a `let`, `const` or `var` declaration or it needs to be in an expression context to distinguish it from a block statement.

Comment: If you are using modern JS and usually elide the semicolons, in this case you must have a semicolon preceding the statement or at the end of the preceding line. Otherwise, the parenthesize expression will be interpreted as a function call on the rvalue of the preceding line.

Comment: Saw this first in Node's repo https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/internal/crypto/pbkdf2.js#L42 
Thanks for explaining!

Comment: MDN docs : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring

Comment: @mrflip I feel as if there should always have been a better way to do this in the first place, very nuanced. Thanks for the heads up, can save people countless time in debugging!